# Python get all stock Tickers

Tags: python

This question have been asked to death but none of the answers provide an actual workable solution. I had found one previously in get-all-tickers:

```
pip install get-all-tickers
```

Recently, for whatever reason, the package get-all-tickers has stopped working:

```
from get_all_tickers import get_tickers as gt
list_of_tickers = gt.get_tickers()
```

gives me the error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 23, saw 46
```

As this is the only package I found that actually gave a complete ticker list (a good check is "NKLA" which is missing from 100% of all other "solutions" I've found on stackoverflow or elsewhere), I now either need a new way to get up-to-date ticker lists, or a fix to this...

Any ideas?

Comment: My thought is that the library might be reading some external data, and is expecting it to be in a certain format, while the actual data has a different format due to some kind of update. That would likely mean you'd have to look at and use the issue tracker for that project, if there is one, to see if there are reports of this issue, or report it yourself, and also see if this has been fixed in a future unreleased version. Have you tried any of that yet? Edit: based on that project's [GitHub page](https://github.com/shilewenuw/get_all_tickers) it hasn't been updated since last August.

Comment: https://github.com/shilewenuw/get_all_tickers/issues/12

Comment: Based on the fact that this seems like a dead project, or an infrequently updated one, you'll likely have to either try fixing it yourself, hoping the owner sees the existing reported issues and fixes it themselves, or find an alternative. StackOverflow isn't in the business of recommending software libraries to people since the answers usually aren't objective. If you want to try fixing this, you'd have to edit the project's source code, and use a debugger to find the line that's giving the error and see if there's a way you can parse the newly changed data format.

Comment: Also, @jonrsharpe linked the project's issue page, and this exact issue was indeed reported 8 hours ago. So, please do due diligence in the future and look at a project's issue tracker and such before posting here - StackOverflow should be a last resort, we shouldn't have to do research that you could've easily done beforehand if you'd looked at all the information that was readily available.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to load this data as CSV.

**Get the CSV from:**

https://plextock.com/us-symbols?utm_source=so

Answer (score 0):

See this answer first: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/1862/38968

> NASDAQ makes this information available via FTP and they update it
> every night. Log into ftp.nasdaqtrader.com anonymously. Look in the
> directory SymbolDirectory. You'll notice two files: nasdaqlisted.txt
> and otherlisted.txt. These two files will give you the entire list of
> tradeable symbols, where they are listed, their name/description, and
> an indicator as to whether they are an ETF.
>
> Given this list, which you can pull each night, you can then query
> Yahoo to obtain the necessary data to calculate your statistics.

Also: New York's Stock Exchange provides a search-function:

https://www.nyse.com/listings_directory/stock

.. and this page seems to have a lot as well - it has Nikola/NKLA at least ;)

https://www.advfn.com/nasdaq/nasdaq.asp?companies=N

Answer (score 0):

This pip package was recently broken, Someone has already raised an issue on the projects github (https://github.com/shilewenuw/get_all_tickers/issues/12).

It was caused by an update to the NASDAQ API recently.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect, but Kaggle has some:
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/jacksoncrow/stock-market-dataset?resource=download

Answer (score -1):

You could use the free alphavantage API https://www.alphavantage.co/documentation/

example:

```py
import requests
key = '2DHC1EFVR3EOQ33Z' # free key from https://www.alphavantage.co/support/#api-key -- no registration required
result = requests.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=NKLA&apikey='+ key).json()

print(f'The price for NKLA right now is ${result["Global Quote"]["05. price"]}.')
```